# IE 11 Enterprise using Compatibility IE 9 Mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web, web-applications

When using IE 11 accessing a certain web application. I get this error while running it. [image]

Does IE 9 not support this?

Comment: Debug what `this` is

Comment: The IE11 (as well as The IE10)compatibility mode ist busted. First oft all you should try it in a real IE9 to make sure this problem actually exists.